# Linking spreadsheets

Tags: excel

I am trying to put a formula on an excel sheet in sharepoint which counts all the 'Y''s in a column of a spreadsheet on the same site but one subfolder down

```
=COUNTIF('https://rcofn.sharepoint.com/sites/XXXXXXX/Shared Documents/YYYYY/ZZZZZZ/[test.xlsx]Sheet1'!$M:$M,"Y")
```

This works fine on the desktop but when I run it on sharepoint I get
`#Value!`.

I am the owner etc of both sheets.